# Trying to replace a set of nos in a file with another set

Tags: bash, sed, replace

file content

```
<page width="595.28000000" height="841.89000000">
<background type="pdf" pageno="61"/>
<layer/>
</page>
<page width="595.28000000" height="841.89000000">
<background type="pdf" pageno="62"/>
<layer/>
</page>
<page width="595.28000000" height="841.89000000">
<background type="pdf" pageno="63"/>
<layer/>
```

I am trying to replace e.g. pageno="62" with pageno="65" and also subsequent page nos i.e. 63->64, 64->65.
I am using bash to do this. The file is very big about 930 pages so sed is slow, is there any fast way to do this?

My script

```
total=$(grep pageno= "$1" | tail -n1 | cut -d'"' -f4)

from="${2}"
to="${3}"

for i in $(eval "echo {${from}..${total}}")
do
    sed -i "s#pageno=\"${i}\"#pageno=\"${to}_new\"#g" "${1}"
    ((to += 1))
done
```

`_new`  will prevent two occurences of same page no, I will delete it later on.

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- all data is nicely formatted as in OP's example (otherwise OP may want to look at a tool specifically designed for processing HTML/XML formatted fields)
- there is at most one instance of `pageno="####"` on any line of input
- `awk` is an acceptable solution

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v pgno=62 '
sub("pageno=\"" pgno "\"","pageno=\"" pgno+1 "\"") { pgno++ }  # attempt replacement on current line and if successful then increment pgno for the next search-n-replace
1                                                              # print current line
' pages.dat
```

This generates:

```
<page width="595.28000000" height="841.89000000">
<background type="pdf" pageno="61"/>
<layer/>
</page>
<page width="595.28000000" height="841.89000000">
<background type="pdf" pageno="63"/>
<layer/>
</page>
<page width="595.28000000" height="841.89000000">
<background type="pdf" pageno="64"/>
<layer/>
```

This should be relatively fast since it requires just a single OS level call (`awk`) and requires a single pass through the input file.

If the results look good and you're using `GNU awk` you can use the `-i inplace` option to update the file in place ...

```
awk -i inplace -v pgno=62 '
sub("pageno=\"" pgno "\"","pageno=\"" pgno+1 "\"") { pgno++ }
1
' pages.dat
```

... otherwise you can write the output to a temp file and then rename/mv accordingly.